# Expand and Collapse UIDatePicker as countDownTimer in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, inline, countdowntimer, uidatepicker

I want to recreate time duration picker similar to [this Project](https://github.com/DylanVann/DatePickerCell) or https://github.com/rajtharan-g/InlineDatePicker or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-E4J0yClmME in SwiftUI. So far I created a DurationPicker Element.

```swift
struct DurationPicker: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var duration: TimeInterval
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIDatePicker {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer
        datePicker.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.updateDuration), for: .valueChanged)
        return datePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker, context: Context) {
        datePicker.countDownDuration = duration
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        let parent: DurationPicker
        
        init(_ parent: DurationPicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        @objc func updateDuration(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
            parent.duration = datePicker.countDownDuration
        }
    }
}
```

My Implementation of it:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var betaAccount = false
    @State private var duration_1: TimeInterval = 0
    @State private var isHidden_1 = false
    @State private var duration_2: TimeInterval = 0
    @State private var isHidden_2 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            isHidden_1.toggle()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Duration 1:")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(duration_1)")
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isHidden_1) {
                        DurationPicker(duration: $duration_1)
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            isHidden_2.toggle()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Duration 2:")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(duration_2)")
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isHidden_2) {
                        DurationPicker(duration: $duration_2)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("countDownTimer")
        }
    }
}
```

The Issue is that the animation not work correctly. As you can see in the following gif, the animation is very strange. How could this problem be resolved?
My idea is, that the picker expand to the bottom from the Text element. When you click on to button again, the picker should collapse to the top. I am really thankful for any type of help.

[image: Animate gif]

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the transition modifier.

Example:

```
HStack{
    if (!isHidden_1) {
          DurationPicker(duration: $duration_1)
               .transition(.move(edge: .top).combined(with: .opacity))
    }
 }
```

I have added the HStack around the view due to a strange behaviour of `.transition`. Sometimes it does not work. The HStack or any other container around the view seems to help. If you want to know more about transitions you can read here [SwiftuiLabs](https://swiftui-lab.com/advanced-transitions/)

Example Gif:

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That is a good idea, but I tried it before. It not quite works perfectly and is also not what I want. 
https://imgur.com/a/apwPdfU
Is it somehow possible to get a clean frame animation like in the examples I linked above?

Comment: @DerEchte did you add the HStack like in my example? Then it should work( it does for me at least). If you want something more advanced, the link I provided should give you enough information to do it.

Comment: Yes I added the HStack. But anyways the animation is not that smooth. Especially with two pickers, there are many bugs. I think I need to solve this Issue somehow with UI Kit